# Each element to a comma bring in upper case (Twig syntax)

Tags: twig

I have an array:

```
{% set colors = "black, red, white" %}
```

I need to remake on:

```
`"Black, Red, White"`
```

Tell me, please, how can I do this?

Comment: what did you try

Comment: I can to split in array `{% set array = colors|split(', ') %}`. And than?

Comment: Then you could foreach the elements and use the filter `capitalize` on each element or just use the [title](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/title.html) filter (added in twig 2.X)

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` filter:

```
{% set colorsArray = "black, red, white"|split(', ') %}
```

Then use

```
{% set colorsArrayCapitalized = colorsArray|map(=> _|capitalize) %}
```

At this point, you have an array

> array('Black', 'Red', 'White')

If you want a comma-delimited string you may use `join`:

```
{% set colorsStringCapitalized = colorsArrayCapitalized|join(', ') %}
```

so you will have this output:

> "'Black', 'Red', 'White'"

P.S. You should use [extensions](https://github.com/dpolac/twig-lambda) to achieve this. if you don't want to use 3rd party extension, you may use a `foreach` instead for the second step

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in filter [`title`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/title.html)

```
{{ "black, red, white" | title }}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/6f9sz4)